# Insert time stamp and user name (or email) on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, audit-logging

I looking for script, that will create audit log in another sheet. In this log it should be:

1)Time stamp
2)User who edited cell
3)The value of the edited cell

I tryed many of tutorial, but I am really new in this and little lost.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

This script will log all activities in the sheet "Logging"

```js
function onEdit(e) { 
  var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var key = Session.getTemporaryActiveUserKey();
  var sName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();  
  if(sName !== "Logging") {
    var value;
    var mA1 = e.range.getA1Notation().split(":")[0];       
    if(typeof(e.value) == 'string') {
      var aCell = e.source.getRange(mA1);
      value = aCell.getValue();
      var form = "'" + aCell.getFormula();
    } else {
      value = e.value;      
    }
    var data = [sName, mA1, timeZone, email, key, value, form];
    e.source.getSheetByName("Logging").appendRow(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: It work nicely. Is it possible to change Time zone to actual Date and Time? Than it will be perfect.

Comment: sure, just use instead of var timezone:
 var datetime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+0100", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");

Comment: Instead of `e.source.getActiveSheet()`, I always use `e.range.getSheet()`. I feel like it's more reliable (but probably it's just as good).

Comment: @Tomasco If this works for you, make sure to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/899642)!